# Paypal Express checkout(PHP): Transaction id is invalid(DoAuthorization)

Tags: php, curl, paypal

I'm using Paypal Express Checkout method for my shopping cart. the paypal payment is working correctly. 
i used the correct `TRANSACTIONID` from my sandbox account after the transaction but the given code always returns the error `Transaction id is invalid`.

```
  $request_params = array
        (
        'METHOD' => 'DoAuthorization',
        'USER' => $api_username,
        'PWD' => $api_password,
        'VERSION' => $api_version,
        'TRANSACTIONID'=>$payment['transaction_id'],
        'AMT' => $order['sub_total'],
        'CURRENCYCODE' => 'USD',
        );

   $nvp_string = '';

   foreach ($request_params as $var => $val)
   {
     $nvp_string .= '&' . $var . '=' . urlencode($val);
   }

   $certFile = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\my_project\certificate\cert_key_pem.txt';

   $curl = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $api_endpoint);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $certFile);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvp_string

   $result = curl_exec($curl);
   curl_close($curl);

   $result_array = $this->NVPToArray($result);
   echo "<pre>"; print_r($result_array); die();
```

the array gives the value as below

```
   Array
   (
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2015-08-10T07:45:36Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => deb2f549572b0
    [ACK] => Failure
    [VERSION] => 85.0
    [BUILD] => 000000
    [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10609
    [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Invalid transactionID.
    [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => Transaction id is invalid.
    [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
   )
```

if you have any idea about such type of errors on Paypal Express Checkout `DoAuthorization` then please help me. thanks

Comment: May be this will help you http://eureka.ucommerce.net/#!/question/1550/How-to-troubleshoot-Transaction-Id-is-invalid

Comment: You need to give more information in order for people to help you. PayPal says you have an invalid transaction ID, you claim it is valid... but you do not tell us what it is/how you got it. Without that info it's he-said she-said, and I bet PayPal is correct :). Certainly I can't help correct whatever error you have with the mystery transaction ID. Could be many things: are both/all calls to sandbox? Did you finish the DoEC? Is the transaction an order? Is it still open/pending? Did you pull the correct field with your $payment[] ref or had it gone missing by the time of the DoAuth call? Etc.

Comment: I've changed the `'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION'=>'SALE',`  to `'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION'=>'ORDER',` and now its working correctly. your suggestion helped me to find out the solution. thank you  `geewiz`.  :)